# GetRouteUrl returns null and RedirectToRoute throws "No matching route found for RedirectToRoute."

Tags: asp.net-routing

```
Page.GetRouteUrl("routename", new { blah = "blah" })
```

Returns null

```
Response.RedirectToRoute("routename", new { blah = "blah" })
```

throws InvalidOperationException("No matching route found for RedirectToRoute.")

I put a breakpoint and checked `System.Web.Routing.RouteTable.Routes` and my routes are there.  I can use them without a hitch in my page code.  What's the deal?

Comment: ASP.NET routing is terribly buggy.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
Response.Redirect(string.Format("~/Blah.aspx/{0}", blah.ToString()));
```

Instead of:

```
Response.RedirectToRoute("routename", new { blah = "blah" })
```

Answer (score 0):

Check your route restrictions. I ran into the same problem before and it turned out that my route restrictions were incorrect.

Hope that helsps